# I am getting Invalid input datetime format of value '11/22/2018' when setting special price in magento 2.3.1

Tags: product, date, special-price, magento2.3.1

I am getting Invalid input datetime format of value '11/22/2018' when setting special price in magento 2.3.1.

[image]

Comment: Is this form date or to date?

Comment: it is in from date

Comment: Actually i have set same thing in both filed with magento's same version but not getting any issue

Comment: use multi store?

Comment: no @SavanPatel only single store

Comment: okay just test  this plugin and check again => https://github.com/fernandofauth/magento2_datetime

Comment: test plugin and tell me working or not? i think it's solved

Comment: @AnsarHusain working or not?

Comment: Hello @SavanPatel same issue

Comment: use this plugin or not?

Comment: i used same plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93712/discussion-between-savan-patel-and-ansar-husain).

Answer (score 3):

This is an official bug. See Magento / GitHub thread [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21666)!

@jcdennen shows a temporary fix until Magento fix it by modifying the Timezone.php file and removing **am** and adding a **0** in **$date .= " 0:00am"**

Composer Install: vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Timezone.php

Other Install: lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Timezone.php

**from:**

```
private function appendTimeIfNeeded($date, $includeTime)
{
    if ($includeTime && !preg_match('/\d{1}:\d{2}/', $date)) {
        $date .= " 0:00am";
    }
    return $date;
}
```

**To:**

```
private function appendTimeIfNeeded($date, $includeTime)
{
    if ($includeTime && !preg_match('/\d{1}:\d{2}/', $date)) {
        $date .= ' 00:00';
    }
    return $date;
}
```

Just remember that modifying core files will be overwritten with an update.

Still not resolved by Magento in M2.3.2.